# MySQL JOIN returns one set with all entries NULL

Tags: mysql, join, group-concat

I have the following query:

```
    SELECT  u.firstName,
            u.lastName,
            u.token,
            c.companyCountry,
            c.system,
            u.paymentOption,
            GROUP_CONCAT(LOWER(r.type)) cardTypes
    FROM    `users` u
    INNER JOIN `customer` c ON (c.`customerID` = users.`customerID`)
    INNER JOIN `routing` r ON (r.customerID = c.customerID AND r.currency = CONVERT(users.transactionCurrency USING utf8))
    WHERE   token = 'TokenNotInTokenTable'
    LIMIT   1
```

If there is is a `token` in the table `users` a result set with the queried fields ist returned. However a result set with fields filled with `NULL` is returned if `token` does not exist. I'm actually struggeling to know how to avoid having such an 'empty' result set; I mean somthing like an empty set if there is no such token.

N.B.: I suspect the `GROUP_CONCAT` to be the cause of my troubles but I'm not sure though.

Comment: i think you are missing `GROUP BY`

Comment: try using LEFT JOIN instead of inner joins used

Comment: @nshah143: Sorry I did not mentioned it. I've tried `LEFT JOIN` on the query and the result was the same. I understand that `JOIN` in general will return `NULL` for non-existing entries. I tried with `GROUP BY` and the result I wanted to have was delivered.

Comment: @SubinCPoonamgode: Wow ok GROUP BY token did solve my problem. I (don't understand yet why but it did the trick!) did understood why. Many thanks!!